# Extracting and transforming a list of tuples to plain columns.[Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the bellow list of tuples in python:

```
[(('A', 'B'), 4), (('B', 'C'), 4), (('C', 'D'), 4)]
```

And I want to extract the Information as shown bellow:

```
[('A', 'B', 4), ('B', 'C', 4), ('C', 'D', 4)]
```

How can I bring it to this form by extracting the inner tuple?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [unpack operator](https://codeyarns.com/2012/04/26/unpack-operator-in-python/) (prefix `*`) to spread out an iterable:

```
tuples = [(('A', 'B'), 4), (('B', 'C'), 4), (('C', 'D'), 4)]
result = [(*t[0], t[1]) for t in tuples]
result # [('A', 'B', 4), ('B', 'C', 4), ('C', 'D', 4)]
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch.

Comment: 8 seconds too late my friend :^)

Comment: General comment - add some text, so it looks more like an answer. In particular naming the unpacking operator may be useful for future readers.

Comment: @kabanus rather than trying to answer as quickly as possible to increase your rep, you both could be looking for an appropriate duplicate, which almost certainly exists ;)

Comment: @Chris_Rands I don't see how think quick answers would be a problem, specially if they do solve the problem.

Comment: @Chris_Rands This has been discussed extensively in meta, and likely you know is controversial. 1) there is no incentive in terms of fake internet points 2) its not always easy, and only very experienced users can find these quickly.  Might not have been the case here, but I think you are fighting a losing battle. No harm in somebody gaining a bit of rep before you dupe-hammer the question.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Also, in case it was not clear, thank you for your thorough moderation effort! Even if I'm the type to occasionally post a quick-and-dirty answer, I appreciate it.